# Razor code within HTML Comments

Tags: html, razor

I have the following piece of code on my Razor page:

```
<ul id="product-tabs-nav"><!--
    --><li><a href="#product-summary">Summary</a></li><!--
    @if (AppSettings.EcommerceEnabled)
    {
        --><li><a href="#product-reviews">Reviews</a></li><!--
    }
--></ul>
```

but it is not working as it seems to be commenting out my razor code (which I thought you would have had to use razor comment tags for).  Does anyone know how to make this work as I need to comment out the white space (I want the `li` tags centrally aligned and the only way to do this is to make them `inline-block` elements which will add the space if I have white-space between them)

Comment: I've never seen something similar. Why the page would be rendering blank spaces between the `li` elements? It makes no sense at all to "comment" every single space between these elements. Each one is been placed on a new line.

Comment: @MelanciaUK white space is being rendered as it is expected behaviour with `inline-block` elements

Comment: I think I got it now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after much playing around with this I have found the error to be with the closing comment tags within the Razor if statement.

I think as it starts with a dash, the compiler is treating this as Razor syntax instead of taking it back to HTML content.  I have solved the problem using `Html.Raw`:

```
<ul id="product-tabs-nav"><!--
     --><li><a href="#product-summary">Summary</a></li><!--
     @if (AppSettings.EcommerceEnabled)
     {
         @Html.Raw("--><li><a href=\"#product-reviews\">Reviews</a></li><!--");
     }
 --></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment in razor c# code you can create llike this `@* *@`

So

```
<ul id="product-tabs-nav"><!-- Some html comment   -->
<li><a href="#product-summary">Summary</a></li>
  @*if (AppSettings.EcommerceEnabled)
  { this is commented
      *@
<li><a href="#product-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
@*
  } this is commented
*@</ul>
```

Comment: I believe the OP already knows that. The question is why regular HTML comment blocks are also putting the code off.

Comment: Hi, I'm not actually wanting the if statement commented out - I am wanting the white space between the `li`s commented out